# Set Xcode archivePath other then project setting for OS X in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, xcode7.3

I was setting **archivePath** in **Custom xcodebuild arguments** for **Xcode Integration plugin version 1.4.11**. However, after upgrading Xcode integration plugin to version 2.0.0 following error was shown:

> **xcodebuild: error: option '-archivePath' may only be provided once**

**Cause:**
This is happening because Xcode integration plugin is also passing the archivePath argument.

> /usr/bin/xcodebuild -scheme Test -workspace
>   TestWork.xcworkspace -configuration Release clean archive
>   -archivePath /Users/Anil/.jenkins/jobs/Test/workspace/Test/build/Release-iphoneos/Test.xcarchive
>   DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=***** -archivePath
>   /Users/Anil/.jenkins/jobs/Test/workspace/Test/build/Test0.5.0.46.xcarchive
>   GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN=NO COPY_PHASE_STRIP=NO

Please note that I was passing

```
-archivePath Users/Anil/.jenkins/jobs/Test/workspace/Test/build/Test0.5.0.46.xcarchive
```

as **Custom xcodebuild arguments** in `Xcode integration` plugin version 1.4.11. However, Xcode integration 2.0.0 plugin is also provided archivePath by its own which is causing the issue.

Please let me know, how would I change archivePath or discard archivePath passed by plugin?

Comment: As an alternative, I have downgraded plugin version to resolve the issue until I find any solution to the issue.